# DMS Integration Insert Documents

Tags: acrobat, dms, acrobat-sdk

I am new to developing plugins for acrobat and c++ so bear with me.

I have implemented the callback to replace method `AVAppOpenDialog` and bring up my own dialog to insert a document. I pass back the path + filename which i turn into an `ASPathName` successfully.

My confusion comes as to how to add these `ASPathName`'s onto the dmsFileSys (`ASFileSysRec`)

```
*outFileSys = (ASFileSys)&dmsFileSys;
```

I am following along to the dms sample in the adobe acrobat sdk 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635344/setting-outaspathnames-for-acrobat-dialogue-return-value/15972414?noredirect=1#15972414)

My Answer answers this question too.

dmsFileSys I presume is your implementation of your own file system. Where you would have to override the default implementations of read/write/delete/etc.

Judging from your other question I presume you do not want to be doing this. If you simply want to pass back a ASPathName, you need to pass it back in an array and create your own ASPathName from the filepath.